# How can I find the typelib identifier of the DirectShow interfaces for use with COM4j

Tags: java, winapi, directshow, com4j, oleview

I'm trying to interact with a webcam from Java on Windows (without going through the FMJ or JMF frameworks) by using COM4j.  However, I'm unable to find the typelib identifier for Direct Show in order to build the interfaces.  The COM4j site recommends using OleView to find the typelib, but I've gone through the list of typelibs there and have had no luck finding anything that looks like it might provide the DirectShow interfaces.

Comment: I was excited this morning to see such a useful looking link in google when I searched on "com4j dshow".  Then I realized it was my own unanswered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loathe as I am to provide a link that might be dead tomorrow, the only help I found was [this](http://www.kohsuke.org/dotnet/directshowTypelib/) site which contains a [link](http://www.kohsuke.org/dotnet/directshowTypelib/DirectShow.tlb) to a tlb file for the DirectShow interfaces.  The COM4j library can interact with this file to generate its interfaces.

Curiously, it didn't create a ClassFactory method for creating the interface I needed, possibly because the ClassFactory naming convention is to name a method 'createXXX' where XXX is the name of the interface, and the interface in question is createDevEnum.  However a little manual tweaking to the ClassFactory class fixed this.